# Get Interaction (Journey) Audit Log

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, setup-audit-log

I'm trying to get the user who created the journey using Rest API found here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getInteractionAuditLog.html

I'm getting this error response:

```
{
"message": "ObjectIds cannot be null or empty",
"errorcode": 10005,
"documentation": ""
}
```

I used the journeyId from the _journey view.
I also tried the definitionid, key but still getting the same error.

I hope someone is able to fixed this issue. TIA.

Best Regards,
Du

Answer (score 2):

It won’t work if you use the journey id from Data Views - you need to retrieve the DefinitionKey of your journey via API using this endpoint: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getInteractionCollection.htm

From the response, you need to take the definition key (not id) of your journey:

```
{
  "count": 10,
  "page": 2,
  "pageSize": 2,
  "links": {},
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "unique-UUID-provided-by-SFMC",
      "key": "a-key-that-is-unique-for-MID",
      "name": "5 days gone by",
      "lastPublishedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "description": "",
      "version": 1,
      "workflowApiVersion": 1,
      "createdDate": "2015-08-17T10:21:38.98",
      "modifiedDate": "2015-08-17T10:22:22.01",
      "activities": [
        {
          "id": "unique-UUID-provided-by-SFMC",
          "key": "WAIT-2",
          "name": "",
          "description": "",
          "type": "WAIT",
          "arguments": {},
          "configurationArguments": {
            "waitDuration": 1,
            "waitUnit": "DAYS"
          },
          "metaData": {
            "waitType": "duration"
          },
          "schema": {
            "arguments": {
              "endDate": {
                "dataType": "Date",
                "isNullable": false,
                "direction": "Out",
                "readOnly": false,
                "access": "Hidden"
              },
              "waitDefinitionId": {
                "dataType": "Text",
                "isNullable": false,
                "direction": "In",
                "readOnly": false,
                "access": "Hidden"
              },
              "waitForEventId": {
                "dataType": "Text",
                "isNullable": true,
                "direction": "In",
                "readOnly": false,
                "access": "Hidden"
              },
              "executionMode": {
                "dataType": "Text",
                "isNullable": false,
                "direction": "In",
                "readOnly": false,
                "access": "Hidden"
              },
              "startActivityKey": {
                "dataType": "Text",
                "isNullable": true,
                "direction": "In",
                "readOnly": false,
                "access": "Hidden"
              },
              "waitQueueId": {
                "dataType": "LongNumber",
                "isNullable": true,
                "direction": "In",
                "readOnly": false,
                "access": "Hidden"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "unique-UUID-provided-by-SFMC",
          "key": "EMAILV2-1",
          "name": "",
          "description": "",
          "type": "EMAILV2",
          "arguments": {},
          "configurationArguments": {},
          "metaData": {},
          "schema": {
            "arguments": {
              "emailSubjectDataBound": {
                "dataType": "Text",
                "isNullable": true,
                "direction": "In",
                "readOnly": true,
                "access": "Hidden"
              },
              "contactId": {
                "dataType": "Number",
                "isNullable": true,
                "direction": "In",
                "readOnly": false,
                "access": "Hidden"
              },
              "contactKey": {
                "dataType": "Text",
                "isNullable": false,
                "direction": "In",
                "readOnly": false,
                "access": "Hidden"
              },
              "emailAddress": {
                "dataType": "Text",
                "isNullable": false,
                "direction": "In",
                "readOnly": false,
                "access": "Hidden"
              },
              "sourceCustomObjectId": {
                "dataType": "Text",
                "isNullable": true,
                "direction": "In",
                "readOnly": false,
                "access": "Hidden"
              },
              "sourceCustomObjectKey": {
                "dataType": "LongNumber",
                "isNullable": true,
                "direction": "In",
                "readOnly": false,
                "access": "Hidden"
              },
              "fieldType": {
                "dataType": "Text",
                "isNullable": true,
                "direction": "In",
                "readOnly": false,
                "access": "Hidden"
              },
              "eventData": {
                "dataType": "Text",
                "isNullable": true,
                "direction": "In",
                "readOnly": false,
                "access": "Hidden"
              },
              "customObjectKey": {
                "dataType": "LongNumber",
                "isNullable": true,
                "direction": "In",
                "readOnly": true,
                "access": "Hidden"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "triggers": [],
      "goals": [],
      "tags": [
          {"name": "Fun Run"},
          {"name": "5K"}
      ],
      "stats": {
        "currentPopulation": 0,
        "cumulativePopulation": 0,
        "metGoal": 0,
        "goalPerformance": 0
      },
      "entryMode": "SingleEntryAcrossAllVersions",
      "defaults": {
        "email": [
          ""
        ]
      },
      "executionMode": "Production",
      "status": "Draft",
      "definitionId": "unique-UUID-provided-by-SFMC"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj, I already tried that but same error as the response. :(

Comment: Can you share your original request? Please post it to your original question

Comment: I also tried to look into this as well and can't really recreate the error message. If the ID I provide is invalid, I'm getting a different message: "Must provide a valid ID or Key parameter" and the same error code: 10005.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens when the journey version is > 1. For the first version the journeyId actually is the journeyId. For later journey versions the journeyId seems to be the definitionId. If you query the audit interface with the definitionId then you get the specific error.

I work around this by calling

`*.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions?$orderBy=ModifiedDate%20DESC`

Then look for the element which has the definitionId and then selecting the id from that object. Querying the audit interface with that id works.